# Power Query - How to extract after delimiter

Tags: powerquery

I have info in a column, that needs to be split into two columns. It can be shown like:

1,000,1111,000 - what we should see is 1,000,111 - 1,000 - or
1,1111,100 - what we should see is 1,111 - 1,100

etc.

I need to separate these columns. I assume the conditions should be "If there are four digits after a comma, separate at this point, into two columns.

It's not immediately obvious how I should fix this. Any thoughts?

EDIT: essentially, the criteria is: If the 4th character after any comma is not another comma, move the 4th character onward onto another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query splits the text string into a list, using its commas as delimiters; then looks at each list entry to find the one that is greater than 3 digits; then inserts a semicolon after the 3rd digit of that entry that is longer than 3 digits; then recombines the list into a text string, with commas; then splits that recombined string into two columns, using the semicolon as the delimiter.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Custom1 = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {"Column1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split(_,","), each if Text.Length(_) > 3 then Text.Insert(_,3,";") else _),",")}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Custom1, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

The table I used to develop/test this is simply this table, which I named Table1:

[image]

The query result looks like this:

[image]